# How to use IN with a query parameter?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, titanium

I have a query like this.

```
SELECT * FROM player_details where name in ('messi','neymar','suarez','alves')
```

I want to execute this query in titanium.
I tried like this

```
var in  = ['messi','neymar','suarez','alves'];
db.execute('SELECT * FROM player_details where name in ?',in);
```

But above code producing error. 
How can i add IN and NOT IN condition in sqlite in titanium ?

Answer (score 0):

A single parameter `?` replaces a single expression.

When you have four values, you need four parameters:

```js
db.execute('SELECT * FROM player_details where name in (?,?,?,?)', in);
```

Comment: length of array is dynamic

Comment: Then you have to construct the query string dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

If the length of the array is dynamic try something like this:

```
var params = ["messi", "neymar", "suarez", "alves"],
    qMarks = new Array(params.length).join("?,") + "?";


db.execute("SELECT * FROM player_details WHERE name in (" + qMarks + ");", params);
```